# Wanted to delete 2 text fields using ExtJS

Tags: extjs5

I have added two text fields in a form panel:

```
    {
        xtype: 'formpanel'
        ,flex: 1
        ,id: 'remove'
        ,defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield'
            ,readOnly: true
        }
        ,items: [{
            bind: {
                value: '{loadDetails.firstname}'
            }
        },{
            bind: {
                value: '{loadDetails.lastname}'
            }
        }
```

I have written the following function for removing the text fields:

```
onRemove: function(){
    Ext.getCmp('remove').setValue("");
}
```

On executing this the console displays that setValue is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.getCmp('remove') returns an instance of your form panel, not of your text fields:

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('remove');
var text1 = form.items.getAt(0);
var text2 = form.items.getAt(1);

text1.setValue("");
text2.setValue("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourForm.reset();
```

will reset all your inputs to the default value

If you need to delete the input field you can try:

```
yourForm.getComponent(//index of the component).destroy();
```

If you need to clear the value of a single field you can get the field like these:

```
form.getComponent(//index)

form.findField(//id of the field)
```

and then call on it `.setValue('');` or `.reset();`

If instead you need to delete all the input fields from the form you can do it like this:

```
form.removeAll();
```